# Set different actions to different list dialog items

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have 3 list within my list dialog but I want each item to do something different when it is clicked. How can I achieve this? I know the code needs to go in the onClick method, but I don't what needs to do so.

```
        final CharSequence[] items = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"};

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Title");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

        }
    }).show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `switch` for example:

```java
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
    switch (item) {
        case 0:
            //action 1
            break;
        case 1:
            //action 2
            break;
        case 2:
            //action 3
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool. What about adding a Cancel button at the bottom?

Comment: @MacaronLover `builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", null);`